# Ifelse Condition in xts Object

Tags: r, if-statement, xts

This is a simple one but I dont get the the correct answer myself.
I have an xts object with NAs and ones

```
require(xts)
set.seed(21)
A <- xts(c(NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), Sys.Date()-10:1)
colnames(A) <- c("A")
```

What I am searching for is the ifelse loop that puts a 0 in A exactly 5 days after the 1 occured:

```
> A
            A
2014-12-23 NA
2014-12-24 NA
2014-12-25 NA
2014-12-26  1
2014-12-27 NA
2014-12-28 NA
2014-12-29 NA
2014-12-30 NA
2014-12-31  0
2015-01-01 NA
```

If by chance there is also a 1 exactly 5 days after the first one (i.e. on 2014-12-31 = 1) then the 1 should be kept.

Comment: Should that be 5 calendar days, or 5 rows?

Comment: I doubt it matters whether you fill with `NA` or any other value !=1 .  Instead of `ifelse`, I'd go with `allones<-which(A==1)` followed with `A[allones+5] <- 1` But as @JoshuaUlrich points out, this works only for 5 rows, not 5 days.  If you want days, you'll have to dig for the date values which are 5 days greater than the values in `A[allones]`

Comment: It should be 5 calender days later

Comment: What if there's no row in your data 5 calendar days later? Should a row be inserted with a value of zero, or should the next observation in your data be set to zero?

Answer (score 3):

The `lubridate` package has the function `days` which makes it easy to add a number of days to a given date. The following has worked for me

```
library(lubridate)
dates.with.1 <- index(A[A==1])
plus.5.days <- dates.with.1 + days(5)
A[index(A) %in% plus.5.days & (is.na(A) | A!=1)] <- 0
```

The indexing in the last line is somewhat complicated and there is probalby a better way to do this. I had to use `index` because indexing directly with dates can not be combined with boolean indexing. That is, the following does not work:

```
A[plus.5.days & (is.na(A) | A!=1)] <- 0
```

Comment: It's a `Date` class object, so `dates.with.1 + 5` works just fine.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich that's right. Thanks for your answer Stibu. lubridate is new to me.

Comment: lubridate is very useful when working with dates and thus definitely worth a look. Check out the functions `dmy`, `ymd`, `ymd_hms` etc. for conversion of strings to date.

Comment: I will definitely do that. Thanks